# When UINavigationbar transition to another ViewController, part of background color auto become gray

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I create a simple app, in main View, there is a navigation bar on top, and a tabBar on button.and the navigation bar's background color is white ,I encounter a
very strange animation.When my app push to another ViewController,part of Navigation Bar's background color become grey before view did appear.Can anyone help me? Thanks.

**PS:I found when I set below property to YES will happen**

```
viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: set your `navigationbar` to opaque. This will help you solve your problem of grey background.

Comment: But my app need navigationbar transparent

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this blur effect is because the entire Tab Bar Controller is being animated underneath the navigation controller, and behind that view is a black UIWindow by default.

So in your `AppDelegate` in function `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` add:

```
 self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Hope this help.